# How to show this joint pdf valid or not?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The question asks if this joint pdf is valid or not. I don't know what is the meaning of being valid of a joint pdf?

\begin{align}
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
xy, \quad 0<x<1, 0<y<1\\
0, \quad \ \ \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: $f(x,y)$ or $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$  is the common notation for a bivariate pdf.

Comment: @callculus42 it is f(x,y) .

Comment: OK. I'll fix it. Does the answer of PC1 help? If yes, then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must integrate to $1$ over the domain, but it integrates to $\frac14$.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \frac14$$